# How to make a basic usable ratingBar?

Tags: android

So for a class i'm taking my group decided to do an android app for our project, which none of us have ever worked with. I know Java, but working with Android is surprisingly different.

I'm trying to just make a 5 star rating that you can click on to change the highlighted rating. Currently it just has the 5 stars all grayed out, and is completely unresponsive.

All the tutorials I can find include a button that shows the int value of the rating, which isn't what i want.

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to what I need to add to the ratingBar to make it usable would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about library [**ProperRatingBar**](https://github.com/techery/ProperRatingBar)?

Example code:

```
<io.techery.properratingbar.ProperRatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:prb_defaultRating="4"
        app:prb_symbolicTick="$"
        app:prb_symbolicTickNormalColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:prb_symbolicTickSelectedColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:prb_totalTicks="5"
        />
```

I hope this helps